# SQL Server not using all CPU cores/threads on server hardware

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

After upgrading our SQL Server's hardware, we noticed in the Windows Task Manager that the SQL instance is only using half of the "threads" available to it (see screenshot)[image: Task Manager].

The server has the following hardware and software:

- Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise 64bit SP1
- Intel Xeon E7-4870 - 4 processors (40 cores, 80 threads)
- Microsoft SQL Server **Standard Edition (64-bit) 10.0.4064**

Running `select cpu_count from sys.dm_os_sys_info` returns 40.

The OS sees all 80 threads. [SQL Server Standard Edition supports 4 Physical CPUs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143760.aspx) which is what we have here.

Why is only half the server's processing power being used?

We have the same hardware and software on two servers and they both exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: This is more suited for Database Administrators SE. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks. I'll post there.

Comment: it will most likely be moved.  Check out my answer and let me know what you get out of that query.

Comment: Related question for 2012: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49930

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SQL database administration and too old to migrate. 

Answer (score 1):

What is your affinity mast set to?  You can find out by querying:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
go
reconfigure
go
exec sp_configure 'affinity mask'
go
```

My guess is that you're not utilizing half of your CPUs, showing you those results.

If you have four processors, you can utilize all of them by setting `affinity mask` to 15, like so:

```
exec sp_configure 'affinity i/o mask', 0
go
reconfigure with override
go

exec sp_configure 'affinity mask', 15
go
reconfigure with override
go
```

The value 15 (binary 00001111) allows SQL Server threads on all four of your processors.

---

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187104.aspx)

Comment: Well, the result I get is:
affinity mask -2147483648 2147483647 -1 -1
But I also get a message: Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Msg 5834, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The affinity mask specified conflicts with the IO affinity mask specified. Use the override option to force this configuration.

Comment: minimum:-2147483648, maxmimum: 2147483647, config_value: -1, run_value:-1

Comment: negative ones. and the minimum is also "negative 2147483648"

Comment: @adinas hmmm that's odd, try setting it to 15.  See my edited post for the details.

Comment: @adinas your minimum and maximum values are just fine, but I'm a bit surprised that you have `-1` for your config_value and run_value.  See my edited post and let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: OK. The result I got back was: Configuration option 'affinity mask' changed from -1 to 15. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Msg 5834, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The affinity mask specified conflicts with the IO affinity mask specified. Use the override option to force this configuration. Is that ok?

Comment: What is your affinity I/O mask set to?  You can find out by running this: `exec sp_configure 'affinity i/o mask' 
go`

Comment: affinity I/O mask,Minimum:-2147483648, maximum:2147483647,config_value:-1 run_value:-1
And yes, those are negative numbers. BTW, Thanks for helping

Comment: @adinas that is extremely odd.  Run this `exec sp_configure 'affinity i/o mask', 0 go reconfigure go`.  Then after you run that, try to run `exec sp_configure 'affinity mask', 15 go reconfigure go` if the first one is successful.

Comment: Well, the first one returned Configuration option 'affinity I/O mask' changed from -1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Msg 5834, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The affinity mask specified conflicts with the IO affinity mask specified. Use the override option to force this configuration.

Comment: The second command returned: Configuration option 'affinity mask' changed from 15 to 15. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Msg 5834, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The affinity mask specified conflicts with the IO affinity mask specified. Use the override option to force this configuration.

Comment: @adinas see my edit again.  I have changed the second query to `reconfigure with override`.  Run those and that should set your configurations correctly.

Comment: Well, this is strange. Now the task manager is showing it using only 12 thread (out of the 80)!. all the others are on zero

Comment: @adinas what query are you running that you think should be utilizing all of these threads?  This isn't the only consideration, but also your maximum degree of parallelism.

Comment: @adinas just to clarify, run `exec sp_configure` and look at your `affinity mask`.  Is it set to 15?  And your `affinity i/o mask`.  Is it set to 0?

Comment: I didn't mention this in the question portion but this is a very high traffic website. so there are many queries being executed all the time from simple selects to complicated stored procedures.

Comment: according sp_configure. 'affinity mask' is 15 in both config_value and run_value. But 'affinity I/O mask' is 0 for config_value and -1 for run_value

Comment: @adinas Hmmm...that's odd.  Run this `exec sp_configure 'affinity i/o mask', 0 go reconfigure with override go`.  Then see what the run_value is for affinity I/O mask after that is executed.

Comment: I ran it. it just returned 'Configuration option 'affinity I/O mask' changed from 0 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.'. But  sp_configure is still showing -1 for run_value of affinity I/O mask. Do I need to restart the SQL Server for it to take effect?

Comment: @adinas you shouldnt' have to.  Run this query and let me know what it says: `select value_in_use
from sys.configurations
where name = 'affinity i/o mask'`

Comment: It returns 'value_in_use' : -1

Comment: Run just this command `reconfigure with override`.  And then run that `select` statement and tell me what the `value_in_use` is.

Comment: @adinas I'm not sure what would be causing your affinity I/O mask to stay at -1, but it sounds like that could be an issue.  When this gets move to Database Administrators SE, there are a lot of DBAs that may know what else to try.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you invested :) I'll move it over... Thanks